# PHP Database connection error: Connection refused . Localhost works fine but real server error occurred

Tags: php, mysql, database, ssh

```
Php Confiq file
<?php
define('DB_SERVER','127.0.0.1:3308');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS' ,'*****');
define('DB_NAME','table_license');

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

Error
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdZUT.png)

[image]

Using HeidiSQL- in Localhost database connection was successful but  the server errors occurred?

Comment: Where is your database located?

Comment: Just to be clear, did you change the credentials after putting it in the live server?

Comment: Check your port 3308 again and also try with define('DB_SERVER','http://localhost:3308');

Comment: server database connect to heidiSql SSH as localhost

Comment: @Arivu you need to understand that HeidiSQL is just a client to view the database. You cannot connect your local database to your server.

Comment: @DhavalPurohit server database register in SSH tunnel as localhost

Comment: @DhavalPurohit thanks for your information. please guide me , how to connect local  database to my server?

Comment: okay than use actual host and port to connect to that database in your server or create another ssh tunnel in your server to use database same as local

Comment: @Arivu you just can't connect your local database to your server.
Server should have the database or the database should be located remotely

Comment: and you are saying that database registered in ssh tunnel to use in the local environment so might it is already remotely located. and you should use that host and port

Answer (score 0):

Try "localhost"  instead of "127...." for DB SERVER

Or try to connect without port,  just ip

Answer (score 0):

When defining the port for your mysqli connection, you have to use the fifth parameter (and not specify it in the host).

Also note that the default port is 3306, so if you're connecting to a shared host, its most likely on the default port (and not on 3308) - if that's the case, then you can omit specifying the port entirely.

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '*****');
define('DB_NAME', 'table_license');
define('DB_PORT', 3308);

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, DB_PORT);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

- [`mysqli::connect` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can try use:

```
define('DB_SERVER', '0.0.0.0');
```

Or

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'db-container'); // if use the docker
```